# How do I spotlight a receiver?

Tags: ncaa-football-11

In NCAA 11, the achievement [In Your Crosshairs](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/ncaa-football-11/achievement/41434-In-Your-Crosshairs.html) is described like this:

> Spotlight a receiver and get an interception on him

How do I spotlight a receiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In Your Crosshairs (Bronze)

What: Spotlight a receiver and get an interception on him in a Play Now or Dynasty game (excludes co-op).

How: To spotlight a receiver you will need to hold L2 and then select the corresponding button above the receiver, tight end or running back. To increase odds of getting this trophy Spotlight the other teams top player on every play. You only need to intercept the pass you do not need to return it for a TD.

[SOURCE](http://playstationlifestyle.net/2010/08/17/ncaa-football-11-trophy-guide/2/)